# Issue with understanding the role of a linear regression alongside a non-linear regression

Tags: r, linear-model, nonlinear-regression, nls

I am working on the movement of fish from the centre of a protected area to a non-protected area. Based on the article by [R. Abesamis](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aqc.730), I applied to my dataset a logistic decay $D = 1/(1+\exp(S\cdot (I-d))$ where $D$ is the proportion of biomass in the middle of the reserve, $d$ is the distance from the centre of the protected area, $S$ is the slope and $I$ is the inflection point. The parameters to be estimated in this model were $S$ and $I$. I successfully estimated those parameters using the `nlmrt` package.

The idea is that the I parameter corresponds to the ochthyological biomass export distance. However, in the scientific article cited above, the author indicates that it is necessary to first of all check with a linear regression if a significant downward trend in fish biomass exist, and only then fit a nonlinear estimation to find the best-fitting logistic decay model for the data. It is on this point that I wonder. Why is it necessary to first test the effect of distance on biomass with a linear regression before using the logistic regression?

Comment: Many people would rather just use plots for that purpose ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply @kjetilbhalvorsen. Unfortunately I am not sure I understand what you mean